# Using s3cmd, how do I retreived the newest folder by "Last modfied" date in an s3 directory

Tags: amazon-s3, s3cmd

I have a directory containing folders whose folder names are created using timestamps. I want use s3cmd to find the file with the most recent "Last Modified" value. If that is not possible, are the solutions to these previous questions the way to go?
[looking for s3cmd download command for a certain date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39479862/looking-for-s3cmd-download-command-for-a-certain-date)

[Using S3cmd, how do I get the first and last file in a folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24544577/using-s3cmd-how-do-i-get-the-first-and-last-file-in-a-folder)

Can s3cmd do this natively, or do I have to retrieve all the folder names and sort through them?

Comment: **Side-note:** These days, it is recommended to use the official AWS CLI rather than `s3cmd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), you can list the most recent file with:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket my-bucket-name --prefix folder1/folder2/ --query 'sort_by(Contents, &LastModified)[-1].Key' --output text
```

The first (oldest) object would be:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket my-bucket-name --prefix folder1/folder2/ --query 'sort_by(Contents, &LastModified)[0].Key' --output text
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. The `--query` needs to be moved after the prefix. Could you correct for future readers?

Comment: Oopsie! Now fixed.